# AICC vs Log Likelihood in Arima

Tags: arima, model-selection, aic, likelihood-ratio

Which is best and why between 2 models A and B where :

- Log likelihood of A < Log likelihood of B
- AICC of A > AICC of B

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Check the existing threads. This question (which is not specific to ARIMA models) has been addressed multiple times before.

Answer (score 1):

Because AICC is based on -log(L), so there is "minus" sign.

Therefore model with lowest AICC is selected according to this criterion.